# Converting Custom list to int array

Tags: c#

I have a program which is giving me a custom list of numbers 'NumberList'.
I converted that list into a custom array with the ultimate goal of converting it to an `int` array. However, the logic I am using is not letting me convert and giving me following error:

> CS0411 C# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Btn()))
     {
          var manager = new NumberManager(Btn());
          var res = manager.Execute();

          NumberWith[] NWArray = manager.NumbersList.ToArray();

          var intArray =  Array.ConvertAll( NWArray, int.Parse);
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and add the code which defines `NumberWith`.

Comment: What does the object look like? Additionally... Why to an Array at all, and not just List<T> for each step?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing what `NumberWith` looks like. What properties does it have? Likely it's an object that wraps an `int` and all you'll need to do is `.Select` that property and then `ToArray`. _Probably_.

Comment: it IS answerable.  The problem is that numberswith is an object with properties.  The final line of code needs to be changed to be NWArray.someproperty

Comment: What does the `NumberManaer` and `NumberWith` look like and more importantly what does `NumbersList` return?

Comment: Side Note: Why is `Btn()` called twice? Shouldn't you call once and cache the results?

Comment: @Austin T French  public class NumberWith
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Matt Burland  public class NumberWith { public int Number { get; set; }

Comment: @ja72 Number List returns a set of number....for example (2,44,45,60,61)

Comment: @AkhilSharma - `NumberList` returns an `IEnumerable<int>` then? "A set of numbers" isn't a specific `C#` type. Please [edit] the question and add more details with minimal code that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code for the `NumbersList` property ? We need to know its exact Type to help you. Also, do you really need to pass through this NumberWith array if ultimately you just want to get an int array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var intArray =  manager.NumbersList.Select((item)=> item.Number).ToArray();
```